# WP Gutenberg, how to import EditableText (as an alternative to RichText )?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I need a Gutenberg block that asks for a string without format

So instead of using `RichText`, I'd say `EditableText` is the component that I need

Documentation here https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/editable-text

In my code the problem is that I cannot even import the component

```js
import { EditableText } from '@wordpress/block-editor'
//import { EditableText } from '@wordpress/components'
import { RichText  } from '@wordpress/block-editor'

console.log(EditableText) // nothing
console.log(RichText)
```

I can see the `RichText` lives in `wp.editor` and in `wp.blocEditor`, but I cannot find `EditableText` anywhere

Why is that? Is this element deprecated? If so, what would be an alternative to add an input block without formatting?

**EDIT:** I can always use a plain `<input>` element, as said here https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/richtext/#unwanted-formatting-options-still-display but I'd like to know why `EditableText` is not available or how I can import it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because the `EditableText` block is not stable yet, in [the current version](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/editable-text), I can see that that it is based on the RichText component:

```
import RichText from '../rich-text';

const EditableText = forwardRef( ( props, ref ) => {
    return (
        <RichText
            ref={ ref }
            { ...props }
            __unstableDisableFormats
            preserveWhiteSpace
        />
    );
} );
```

Unfortunately, it crashes when I try to use it (I may be doing it wrong), and using the `RichText` as the code from `EditableText` suggests does not work.

**Solution** : [the documentation of RichText](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/richtext/#unwanted-formatting-options-still-display) indicates that you can use the `formattingControls` attribute even though it is not recommended for "just text input": https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/richtext/#unwanted-formatting-options-still-display

Alternatively, to get a "pure" Gutenberg implementation of your `input` field, you can use [TextControl](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/components/src/text-control) (beware of the `imports` in the example, it is located in `@wordpress/components` and not `@wordpress/blocks`):

```
import { TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { withState } from '@wordpress/compose';

const MyTextControl = withState( {
    className: '',
} )( ( { className, setState } ) => ( 
    <TextControl
        label="Additional CSS Class"
        value={ className }
        onChange={ ( className ) => setState( { className } ) }
    />
) );
```

Comment: Please also note that contrary to what the doc says, the `formattingControls` is deprecated in favor of `allowedFormats` (you get a warning in debug mode if you use formattingControls).